# Show the button when input value reaches 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have input box where in it increases the product quantity by clicking on +/- icons. 
By default there will be an "**Add**" button, clicking on that it enables +/- input filed and hide the "**Add**" button. Now when the input value reaches `0` I need to show the "**Add**" button and hide the input field.

Here is my script used

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
        $(".incrmentrs").show();
      $(this).hide();
});
$(function () {

    $('.add').on('click',function(){
        var $qty=$(this).parent().find('.qty');
        var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
        if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
            $qty.val(currentVal + 1);
        }
    });
    $('.minus').on('click',function(){
        var $qty=$(this).parent().find('.qty');
        var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
            $qty.val(currentVal - 1);
        }
    });
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gsmbcz9r/1/)**

Comment: @DharaParmar Added the fiddle. Sorry missed to include that in first go.

Comment: Simple, check the value of input on every click, if value is 0 Apply the code 
`$(button).show();
      $('.incrmentrs').hide();`

Comment: @user3932810 ok added answer below..have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/ovt6f7ev/

Change minus click event code like this:

```
$('.minus').on('click',function(){
            var $qty=$(this).parent().find('.qty');
            var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
            console.log(currentVal)
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 1) { // check if value is 1 or more then minus value
                $qty.val(currentVal - 1);
            } else { // else show button
               $(".incrmentrs").hide();
               $("button").show(); 
            }
 });
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/b0y/pen/bepgMp :D 
made a similar pen.. ;) 
Upvoting

Answer (score 0):

Add this event to the `<input>`

```
$(".qty").change('input', function () {
   if ($(this).val() == 0) {
      $(".incrmentrs").hide();
      $("button").show();
   }
});
```

And trigger the event on minus button `click` with:

```
$qty.trigger("change");
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/of8t2h19/)

Watch events on the `<input>` and not the `<button>`. In this case the event is firing also when a user writes directly to the `<input>`.